# Make No Password Required on local linux (tty) login

Tags: linux, login

I want to allow a user that is logging in to the system locally (ie. keyboard & mouse) to not have to enter a password. Is this possible? I have the system locked down extremely well with SSH, and it sits with me always, so I it is not an issue.

Comment: Possible? Yeah probably. A terrible, bad, awful, awful, terrible idea? Absolutely.

Comment: @Sammitch, on an embedded development system (pre-release), that you are actively developing, where every time you boot, you want to save a few seconds not having to deal with the password of the user account, I think this is an absolutely fantastic idea that should deserve a gold medal. OPs question is helping me find a solution. I'm happy he asked so I don't have to ask myself. I too find his reasoning somewhat naive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be bad security but as noted if you have physical access to a non encrypted laptop you could get into the files and reset passwords with a linux live cd/usb or sometimes the grub menu lets you boot to recovery root and you can change the password.

Do you mean a virtual console or the default graphical console?

Login Settings (GNOME/KDE) should have option to boot to desktop without password.

For Virtaul Consoles

Arch linux has a guide which I think should work for other systemd distros.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console

run

```
systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

and put the following into the file

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I $TERM
```

I think that should let you autologin to the first console.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It says 'root (automatic login)' but then It still asks for password. Probably, something should be tuned in PAM configuration.

Comment: I have the same issue, @0x2207 !!

Answer (score 2):

Following from the great information from @Roman I modified his answer somewhat for the solution on my system, which was Debian. For anyone else needing this; for Debian, edit `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty\@tty1.service` and add `--autologin root` to the line which begins with `ExecStart=-` so that it reads:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear %I $TERM
```

Hope that helps. I realize it is a security risk in most cases. But when it is an embedded router that is strapped to the bottom of my desk and all external authentication is done with 2 factor authentication... I am not too worried.

Thank you for the help @Roman!

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to get agetty to automatically login regular user without a password. It still requires it. But as I am running standalone workstation without internet connection for my purpose, I found that just clearing the user's password does the trick. Now autologin works. Hope this was better documented in agetty's manpage.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/499487)

Answer (score 0):

## 1. - The Lazy Edit on /etc/passwd

change the **x** from

`radvd:x:109:65534::/run/radvd:/usr/sbin/nologin`
to
`radvd::109:65534::/run/radvd:/usr/sbin/nologin`

(after the first colon) and the Password has gone, this works also in case you lost the root password.

## Using the "Official Way" with [passwd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd) command

`passwd -d <user>`

Comment: I updated the link to `passwd`, but to remove `root` password is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Niki i agree with you, but i said that, in case someone forgot the Password. in this case, the way will be the same and thanks for updating the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found this slightly different method worked for me on Debian 10 with GUI disabled:

`sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`

Change `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM`

to `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-f -p -- \\u' --noclear -a USERNAME %I $TERM` (replacing `USERNAME` with the desired user)